# passing data to nested views

Tags: zend-view, zend-framework3

I tried first time with nested views in zend3. My templates will be loaded but no data appears, instead of that I get an error.

Here what I tried:

controller/index

```
$view = new ViewModel();
    $projectView = new ViewModel(['project' => $this->projectTable->fetchAll()]);
    $projectView->setTemplate('import/project/index');
    $primaryUnitView = new ViewModel(['unit' => $this->unitTable->fetchAll()]);
    $primaryUnitView->setTemplate('import/unit/index');

    $view->addChild($projectView, 'projectview')
         ->addChild($primaryUnitView, 'unitview');
    return $view;
```

My view index.phtml

```
<div class="row content">
<?= $this->projectview ?>

<?= $this->unitview ?>
```

one of the childviews:

```
<?php 
foreach ($projects as $project) : ?>
    <tr>
    <td><?= $this->escapeHtml($project->projectname) ?></td>
     <td><?= $this->escapeHtml($project->shortcut) ?></td>
     <td><?= $this->escapeHtml($project->Number) ?></td>
     <td><?= $this->escapeHtml($project->description) ?></td>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

The other one is the same based on another table.

Each of the childviews comes with the same error, here the first one as example

> Notice: Undefined variable: projects in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs...\module\Import\view\import\project\index.phtml on
>   line 28
>
> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs...\module\Import\view\import\project\index.phtml on
>   line 28

Line 28 is the head of the foreach loop, for the other childview I get the same error. So passing the data to the view might be wrong. The same view worked properly before I started trying nested views.

So what would be the correct way to pass the data to the childviews. And in this case how to make the constraint between the two views?

Comment: You need to fix a typo. You are passing `$project` into the view but not `$projects`.

Comment: I think it is not the reason, because it worked before. anyway  I of course tried your suggestion. I get an error undefined property, so I changed back. But I will check further with the naming.